# Decomposing time series with 2 trends

Tags: r, time-series

I have some web data from 2011 to present, and I would like to look at its seasonality in R. However, in June 2014, a change to the website was made that boosted the numbers by a lot, throwing off my seasonality analysis. Is the best approach to just examine the data up until this change, or is there a way to account for more than one trend in the decomposition?

Comment: what kind of methods have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, to look at the seasonal components, I did                                          `t.data = ts(web$data, start = c(2011,1), frequency = 12)  
t.data.components <- decompose(t.data)  
t.data.components$seasonal`  But they change pretty noticeably if I only look at the data up till June 2014